# Python 2.6 regex, escaping chars in windows

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex that finds if there is a period or a " (quote char) or a word in a line. I have to escape the period and the " chars.

```
res = re.match(ur"\"|\.|\w+",line)
```

The regex seems to work in Linux but in Windows I amn getting a syntax error. Any suggestions?

Comment: It does not work! It seems that the problem is with the "u" before the "r". If I only write r"...,it works ok!

Comment: Are you calling this from the commadline? There should be no difference between unix and windows for this.

Comment: I am calling from IDLE with 2.6 from Windows and I have the problem. If I call from IDLE in Linux, I do not have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have double quotes in your string, then enclose your string in single quotes, so you don't need to escape the double quotes.

```
res = re.match(ur'"|\.|\w+',line)
```